# Get vim to display number of commas in one line

Tags: vim

I have a long line with many commas. I would like to know the number of commas in a line. How can i do this using vim?

Also, I want to do this for characters other than comma.

Specifying the line number and a character should give me the number of occurrences of that character.

for example :

```
:charmap/50/,
```

should give me the number of commas in line 50.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
:s/,//gn
```

reports the number of `,` on the current line without doing the substitution

```
:50s/,//gn
```

does the same for line 50.

See `:h s_flags` for `/n`.

Comment: Is there any way to append `,0` to all lines having 5 commas in VIM?

Comment: Probably. You should try something.

Comment: I actually found a solution, I posted the answer [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17506/append-0-to-all-lines-having-2-commas-and-not-more-than-2-commas), but I feel there is far better solutions.

Answer (score 19):

Just make a search and count matches :

```
:s/,//gn
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about VIM, but I get desired results as below.

```
# cat t.txt 
,,,, ,, ,, ,,
,, ,   ,,,, 
,, 
,,
 ,

    ,,,,,
```

and here is how I count the no. of commas in each line:

```
# sed 's/[^,]//g' t.txt | awk '{ print length }'
10
7
2
2
1
0
5
```